# Why sbt makes resolution for all dependencies when only one changed?

Tags: scala, sbt, ivy

When I change one of project's dependencies, then `sbt` runs resolution for all dependencies(not only for the one which is changed). It is especially time consuming when such redundant resolution is made for each project in multi-module project.

Why sbt makes such redundant resolution ? Is there a way to make resolution more intelligent ?

Comment: If a dependency changes then potentially the new versions could also have changed to its dependencies and so on. The only safe thing to do is re-create the entire dependency tree. (Don't forget that creating dynamic dependencies, will force ivy to constaintly re-check the repository to figure out what the latest revision of a dependency might be).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main reason is because sbt needs to resolve *conflicts*.  Not only that, but ivy needs to resolve all -SNAPSHOT dependencies frequently to ensure it has up-to-date information.   This is because, by default, sbt uses a "latest" conflict resolution manager, rather than a "nearest" used by maven.  This, in my experience, leads to less issues with artifact versions.  However, it does mean, as Mark states, that it will recreate the entire dep tree.

All resolution in sbt is delegated down to ivy.  To make it more intelligent, you'd have to create hooks for Ivy or otherwise replace the dependency management library sbt uses.   In this resolution case, I think the only thing that can be done is improving the cache in a way that drops the amount of time it takes to restore previous cached artifact information.